# MySQL Check Point Within a polygon stored within a table

Tags: mysql

A little out of my depth with this one.

I've ran the query:

```
SELECT ST_Contains(
    PolygonFromText('
      POLYGON((
        60.930551 -0.775212, 
        60.332866 -0.417906, 
        59.935582 -0.887788, 
        59.837354 -1.156991, 
        58.919848 -2.577975, 
        58.378359 -2.935748, 
        57.934035 -3.75355, 
        57.761068 -3.563538, 
        57.859628 -1.643417, 
        57.538993 -1.423404, 
        56.382748 -2.522191, 
        55.846937 -1.945553, 
        55.618743 -2.262236, 
        55.463878 -2.131039, 
        55.42282 -2.162707, 
        54.968355 -3.03811, 
        54.960564 -3.232644, 
        54.929382 -3.449798, 
        54.540197 -4.141976, 
        54.467094 -5.149036, 
        55.657203 -6.713395, 
        56.947221 -7.700598, 
        57.681709 -7.656722, 
        58.298006 -7.239903, 
        60.930551 -0.775212))'),
 PointFromText("POINT(57.05 -4.49)"));
```

Which returns a `1` to confirm that `57.05, -4.49` is indeed within the polygon.

I want to store the polygon data in my database and did so with:

```
INSERT INTO polygons (`ownerID`, `polygon`) 
VALUES ("test", PolygonFromText('POLYGON((60.930551 -0.775212, 60.332866 -0.417906, 59.935582 -0.887788, 59.837354 -1.156991, 58.919848 -2.577975, 58.378359 -2.935748, 57.934035 -3.75355, 57.761068 -3.563538, 57.859628 -1.643417, 57.538993 -1.423404, 56.382748 -2.522191, 55.846937 -1.945553, 55.618743 -2.262236, 55.463878 -2.131039, 55.42282 -2.162707, 54.968355 -3.03811, 54.960564 -3.232644, 54.929382 -3.449798, 54.540197 -4.141976, 54.467094 -5.149036, 55.657203 -6.713395, 56.947221 -7.700598, 57.681709 -7.656722, 58.298006 -7.239903, 60.930551 -0.775212))')");
```

But I am now struggling to run the initial ST_Contains query whilst also returning the polygon from the table.

```
SELECT @Test := polygon FROM polygons where ownerID = 'test';
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(@Test), PointFromText("POINT(57.05, -4.499)"));
```

Returns a null response and I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but unfortunately it evades my basic skills and googling has returned lots of examples where the polygon is defined in the query, but not where it is stored in a table.

How can I check to see if a point is within a polygon that is stored in the table `polygons`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When storing the value to your variable `@Test` you forgot to select the geom value as text and your POINT has a comma in it.

```
SELECT @Test := ST_AsText(`polygon`) FROM `polygons` WHERE ownerID = 'test';
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(@Test), ST_PointFromText("POINT(57.05 -4.499)"));
```

Or without converting to WKT -

```
SELECT @Test := `polygon` FROM `polygons` WHERE ownerID = 'test';
SELECT ST_CONTAINS(@Test, ST_PointFromText("POINT(57.05 -4.499)"));
```

Or just -

```
SELECT *,
    ST_AsText(`polygon`),
    ST_CONTAINS(`polygon`, ST_GeomFromText("POINT(57.05 -4.499)"))
FROM `polygons`
WHERE `owner_id` = 'test';
```